# Bash if conditions of variables within intervals

Tags: bash, shell, arithmetic

I have some data spread over time intervals, and I want to take some of those data within the time intervals. For example, I have data at times within 1..9, 11..19, etc., and I want to take data within 1-2, then 11-12, etc.

This will be part of a more complex `bash` script, in which I want to include this condition, with a `if` cycle, to isolate the times where I can catch the data.

I was thinking something like:

```
if (( $t_initial & $t_final )) in (begin1, fin1) or in (begin2, fin2) ...
```

where `t_initial` and `t_final` are calculated separately, by the script itself.

I can not write this condition in `bash` syntax. I found some other solutions, but they seem extremely long and inconvenient, so I am here to ask simpler and more readable solutions.

---

It is important that the code works properly with floats. I am trying to fix the OP solution for this, but still can't find a way.

Comment: I don't get it. Data should have a single timestamp, why do you have 2 variables t_initial and t_final?

Comment: @LatinSuD, Because I am working in phase, more than times, and I have to get only same phase intervals between given time intervals :)

Comment: What happens if `t_initial=1, t_final=3,  begin1=2,fin1=4`? Is that a match or not?

Comment: @LatinSuD, no it is not. `begin` and `fin` are intended to be the extreme times of a given interval. if the times are not within the intervals, then the condition is not satisfied.

Comment: @Py-ser, you need to give us more detail. what is the input? what is the actual values of `t_initial` and `t_final`? what is the current output? what is your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` doesn't natively support a range comparison, nor floating-point numbers, so we have to do some of that ourselves. I'm also going to define a function, and use `bc` for floating-point calculation. Here is the end result and test suite:

```
# Call as `compareRanges start end b1 f1 b2 f2 b3 f3...`
compareRanges() {
    local t_initial=$1
    local t_final=$2
    shift 2
    while [ ${#@} -gt 1 ]
    do
        local in_range=$(bc <<<"$t_initial >= $1 && $t_final <= $2")
        if [ $in_range = 1 ]
        then
            # Debugging output to stderr - can be removed:
            echo "[$t_initial,$t_final] is within [$1,$2]" >&2
            return 0
        fi
        shift 2
    done
    # Debugging output to stderr - can be removed:
    echo "[$t_initial,$t_final] is not within any ranges." >&2
    return 1
}
# Basic integers from the example
compareRanges 1 3 2 4 && echo BAD || echo OK
compareRanges 1 3 1 3 && echo OK || echo BAD
compareRanges 1 3 0 4 && echo OK || echo BAD
# Fractional numbers
compareRanges 1.5 2.5 1.1 2.2 && echo BAD || echo OK
compareRanges 1.5 2.5 0.3 3.1 && echo OK || echo BAD
# Multiple ranges
compareRanges 5 7 1 4 2 6 3 9 && echo OK || echo BAD
compareRanges 5 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 && echo BAD || echo OK
```

The `compareRanges` function takes at least two arguments. The first is your `t_initial`, and the second is your `t_final`. It can take arbitrarily many other arguments in pairs after that, which are your `begin1`, `fin1`, `begin2`, `fin2`, in order.

The first test case compares the ranges in the comments on the question: 1-3 and 2-4.

```
compareRanges 1 3 2 4 && echo BAD || echo OK
```

So `1` is `t_initial`, `3` is `t_final`, `2` is `begin1`, and `4` is `fin1`.

When you want to use multiple ranges, you list them all out in pairs afterwards:

```
compareRanges 5 7 1 4 2 6 3 9 && echo OK || echo BAD
```

Here we test against 1-4, 2-6, and 3-9. In the `while` loop we look at each pair in turn and compare it against `t_initial` and `t_final`.

Because `bash` doesn't support fractional numbers we use [`bc`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bc), an arbitrary-precision calculator. Its input is given by the `<<<"$t_initial >= $1" ...` part: that feeds the string into standard input. `$1` is the start of the range we're currently looking at in this iteration of the loop, and `$2` is the end; we compare both the lower and upper bounds at once with `&&`. `bc` will output `1` when the comparisons are true, and `0` when one is false. We save the result in `in_range`, and the function succeeds (`return 0`) when both our tests were true.

Fractional numbers can just be specified with their ordinary decimal form:

```
compareRanges 1.5 2.5 0.3 3.1 && echo OK || echo BAD
```

`bc` will handle numbers with as many fractional digits as you want and with whatever magnitude you need.

At the end, if none of the boundary pairs matched, we fail (`return 1`). You can use the function as:

```
if compareRanges $t_initial $t_final 2 4 11 19
then
    ...
fi
```

The test suite should print all "OK" when you run it.

---

Alternatively, other shells (such as [`zsh`](http://www.zsh.org/)) **do** support fractional variable values. If you could run your script in one of those you could avoid the use of `bc`, although the comparison is still better off in a function. At least in `zsh`'s case they are floats, so they're not necessarily accurate; `bc` will always be correct.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you would like this solution. It has 2 features:

- No external programs are required
- It uses a function, so at least it hides the complexity of the comparisons

This is it:

```
#!/bin/bash

# The comparing function
function compareInterval {
 t1=$1
 t2=$2

 shift 2

 while (( "$2" )); do
   if ((  $t1 >= $1  &&  $t2 <= $2 )); then
     # got match
     return 0
   fi
   shift 2
 done

 return 1
}

# sample values
t_initial=2
t_final=4

# Invocation. Compares against 1-3, 3-5, 2-5
if compareInterval  $t_initial $t_final  1 3  3 5  2 5; then
 echo Got match
fi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have never used functions in bash, could you tell me the logic behind the separation of the comparison? how can it understand to compare between 1 and 3, and not between, i.e., 3 and 3, or 5 and 2 (in the example above)?

Comment: Separation is cosmetic only. The important thing is parameter number. They are processed in pairs.

Comment: does this work with decimal numbers too?

Comment: @Py-ser Unfortunately not. I think that feature would require the use of an external program like `bc`.

Comment: Nice answer. I get the feeling that both numbers need to be within the range, so the condition would need to be `(( ($1 <= $t1 && $t1 <= $2) && ($1 <= $t2 && $t2 <= $2) ))`

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of shameless rip-offs of LatinSuD’s answer that handle floating point. 
You’ll notice that his answer boasts “No external programs are required.” 
This one uses the calculator program, `bc`, as he suggested:

```
#!/bin/bash

# The comparing function
function compareInterval {
 t1=$1
 t2=$2

 shift 2

 while (( "$2" ))
 do
   # if ((  $t1 >= $1  &&  $t2 <= $2 ))
   bc_result=$(echo "print $t1 >= $1  &&  $t2 <= $2" | bc)
   if [  "$bc_result" = 1 ]
   then
     # got match
     return 0
   fi
   shift 2
 done

 return 1
}

# sample values
t_initial=2.3
t_final=4.2

# Invocation. Compares against 1-3, 3-5, 2-5
if compareInterval  $t_initial $t_final  1 3  3 5  2 5
then
 echo Got match
fi
```

This simply takes the `if ((  $t1 >= $1  &&  $t2 <= $2 ))` test and sends it to `bc`,
and then captures the output from `bc`.

---

Another approach is to normalize the numbers to integers by multiplying by a power of ten. 
This requires that you have a maximum number of decimal digits. 
For example, if no data point has more than three digits to the right of the decimal point,
we can multiply everything by 1000.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Normalize function: it multiplies a floating point number by 1000
# without using floating point arithmetic.
normalize()
{
  case "$1" in
    *.*)
        result=$(echo "$1"000 | sed 's/\(.*\)\.\(...\).*/\1\2/')
        ;;
    *)
        result="$1"000
  esac
  echo "$result"
}

# The comparing function
function compareInterval {
 t1=$(normalize $1)
 t2=$(normalize $2)

 shift 2

 while (( "$2" ))
 do
   a1=$(normalize $1)
   a2=$(normalize $2)
   if ((  $t1 >= $a1  &&  $t2 <= $a2 ))
   then
     # got match
     return 0
   fi
   shift 2
 done

 return 1
}

# sample values
t_initial=2.3
t_final=4.2

# Invocation. Compares against 1-3, 3-5, 2-5
if compareInterval  $t_initial $t_final  1 3  3 5  2 5
then
 echo Got match
fi
```

If the parameter to the `normalize` function is a simple integer
(i.e., a number with no decimal point, e.g., `17`)
we can multiply by 1000 simply by appending `000`, so `17` → `17000`. 
If the parameter to `normalize` is a floating point number
(i.e., it contains a decimal point, e.g., `42.5`),
we still append the `000`,
and then use `sed` to remove the decimal point and everything after the third digit. 
The `sed` command `s/\(.*\)\.\(...\).*/\1\2/` takes a string like *abcdef**.**ghijkl*
and returns *abcdefghi*,
so `42.5` → `42.5000` → `42500` (i.e., 42.5 × 1000).

It may be possible to do this string manipulation entirely in `bash`, without using `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

The "11..19" thing you are asking about is called brace expansion.

You could use either `eval {$t_initial..$t_final}` ,

...or

`` if `seq $t_initial..$t_final`==$somevalue ``